# Angular(2/4/5/6) Custom validator error message not showing

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I'm trying to get my validator to show up correctly using a form custom validator, but I'm not sure how to call it. I tried BroadcastForm.controls.errors.customTimeValidator() in the html side but it doesn't work correctly. Appreciate your help!

**broadcast.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.BroadcastForm = this.fb.group({
        datetime: [
            datetime,
            Validators.compose([Validators.required, this.customTimeValidator()]),
        ],
    });
}

customTimeValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
        const minDate = new Date();
        minDate.setSeconds(0);
        this.minTime = minDate.getTime() + 59 * 1000;
        const forbidden = control.value <= minDate;
        return forbidden ? { forbiddenName: { value: control.value } } : null;
};
}
```

**broadcast.component.html**

```
<div class="validation-error" *ngIf="
   BroadcastForm.controls.datetimeOption.value === 'false' &&
   BroadcastForm.controls.errors.customTimeValidator()"> //how do I call customTimeValidator correctly?
   Please select a future date/time
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

`BroadcastForm.controls.errors.customTimeValidator()`

to

`BroadcastForm.controls['datetime']['errors']['forbiddenName']`

Actually you could find all errors using `json` pipe

`{{ BroadcastForm.controls['datetime']['errors'] | json }}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say, the accepted answer is disgusting, both to look at and to use.

Use something simpler, cleaner, and documented :

```
BroadcastForm.get('datetime').hasError('forbiddenName')
```

Comment: HasError only return boolean that doesn’t show the details of the error. And for multi-level form array or form group, it s easier to loop through the fields and levels. fieldname.errors.validatorfn is used in angular website too (https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)

Comment: @hugomac and where do you see the error value being used in the code ? He asked for a way to display it, implying the condition isn't respected. There is no multi-level here either, and you can still get the errors very simply even with multi-level. As for the documentation, they use a different **syntax**, which is cleaner than the array notation. Finally, I'm not saying you are wrong, I'm saying that the syntax you use is ugly and not appropriated to his case.

Comment: Oh. In his case, there is an error value in it that probably wanna show to the users. Understanding the whole form object is important to write their own api and library.  I would say hasError() is just an API offered by Angular team. Even hasError() may return false value in some scenarios (you may google it). Using default API is clean but may not be the best approach all the times. Be flexible. Using array-like format is for dynamic use when loop through the field name, a real life approach. Anyway, it s my opinion and may not healthy to discuss this here. Sorry for that.

Comment: Yeah, but not in this case. You answer a question, with a context and given code : if you want to make a course, [it's over there](https://www.udemy.com/) ! and it works in any case that is planned by Angular. Most of the times when it "doesn't work", it is during async validators, where the status is "pending", meaning neither valid nor invalid. And yes, that is your opinion, you're totally entitled to it and I respect that. But I have mine too ! And no problem, we're talking, don't apologize for defending yourself :)